# Locked Q shows as {on hold}

Tags: support

Why does this Q report as {on hold}:

[Wayback Machine archiving broken with HTTPS](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/108425/wayback-machine-archiving-broken-with-https)

when it is actually locked?

> If this question can be reworded to fit the rules in the help center, please edit the question.

Editing is not possible for normal users.

Some extra details:

I am assuming a rejected migration does not presuppose off site here (eg sometimes OPs ask for migration because they think they will get a better response on another site).

I am assuming the Q’s status at present is as set at the time of the ‘migration’ and ‘hold’ notices.

I accept that the Q (as it stands) is off topic here and at SU.

By the looks of it, the Q was here, there and back in less than 5 hours. Seems unfair to reduce the opportunity for this OP to improve the post to such a short interval (relatively) just because it looked suitable on SU (better than looking absolute rubbish!). {on hold}’s limit is 5 *days*, not hours.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is only a "stub" of the question which resulted from a rejected migration.  These can be unlocked and reopened on this side, so it was left for a bit in case there was any movement in that direction.

In cases like this, you can flag to have the stub deleted, as it can't be deleted by a user, even with the proper reputation.

Comment: Not a clue what the rationale is.  Migration is a bit of wizardry, so it's likely to guard against a question being in limbo between the two sites.